# Getting LINQ to Firebird to work

Tags: c#, .net, linq, firebird

I'm trying to generate an entity model from a Firebird database using the Entity Data Model Wizard, but it dies loading the data for the "Choose Your Database Objects" step with the error:

> ### Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> An error occurred while connecting to the
>   database. The database might be
>   unavailable. An exception of type
>   'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException'
>   occurred. The error message is: 'An
>   error occurred while executing the
>   command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details.
>
> The inner exception caught was of type
>   'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException',
>   with this error message: 'Dynamic SQL
>   Error
>
> SQL error code = -104
>
> Token unknown - line 6, column 8
>
> SELECT'.
>
> The inner exception caught was of type
>   'FirebirdSql.Data.Common.IscException',
>   with this error message: 'Exception of
>   type
>   'FirebirdSql.Data.Common.IscException'
>   was thrown.'.'.
>
> [ OK ]

I certainly believe it should work from [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/01/12/beta-of-firebird-ado-net-provider-with-entity-framework-support-available.aspx) on the ADO.Net team blog.

I'm able to browse tables and definitions using server explorer, so I think it's safe to discount connectivity/permissions issues, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to what else to check to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the comment on this blog post](http://blog.cincura.net/228839-firebird-ado-net-data-provider-2-5-0-beta-1-for-net-3-5-2-0-with-entity-framework-support/), Firebird 1.5 is not support for LINQ to Firebird, even though it is supported version according to [the Firebird website](http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=files).

Comment: As I happen to be integrating with a third party's server to report from it, and cannot upgrade it, the short answer is that it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

The blog post you speak about is beta version

the final release is on [Jiri blog](http://blog.vyvojar.cz/jirka/archive/2009/05/22/ann-firebirdclient-2-5-final-released.aspx)
or on [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=files&id=netprovider)
or [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/06.aspx)

Comment: I downloaded the various bits from the Firebird site, and should have the RTM versions of all bits as of today.